# Does Cognito User Pool Authorizer in Gateway API require all requests to be signed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html#apigateway-invoke-api-integrated-with-cognito-user-pool) for using Cognito User Pool Authorizer with Gateway API says only that I should:

> 3. Call API methods configured with a user pool authorizer, supplying the unexpired token in the Authorization header or another header of
>      your choosing.

This is echoed by some other texts on the web.

However, when I try using the token, I get an error message that informs about missing `Credentials`, `Signature`, `Signed Headers` params (and the `Date` header). The token I am using is most likely correct as passes the test in the authorizer's web gui.

My question has two parts:

- Does that mean that using the Cognito User Pool Authorizer requires
  me to sign each request? Is there some way to configure it to just
  accept a valid token?
- If I want to keep my HTTP calls to Amazon Gateway simple and
  authorize them with just the token (so that they can easily be
  performed by hand, from Python backend etc.), am I forced to write a
  custom authorizer using Lambda? Or is there some better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito User Pool authorizer does not require a signature on the request. You simply have to pass the JWT version of the OpenID Connect identity token produced by Cognito in the authorization header of each request.

```
result.getIdToken().getJwtToken()
```

This should answer both your questions.

I think you are getting confused with the Cognito Identity service, which exchanges a valid identity from a public identity provider (Facebook, Amazon, User Pools, etc) for temporary AWS Credentials. You can use the AWS credentials from the Cognito Identity service to sign requests.

If you are only using User Pools, the result of a successful authentication are an OIDC identity token and a JWT access token. API Gateway, when configured with a User Pool authorizer, uses the identity token to authenticate a request.

Comment: I was using the correct token when I got the error (as I mentioned, it got validated in the ui and the decoded JWT looked fine). The error dissappeard when I did another deployment as a different stage - currently I have two deployments, seemingly identical, one works and the other doesn't. Should I write that off as a random glitch?

Comment: Definitely not. This shouldn't happen. The issue won't go away even if you re-deploy to the original stage? If the issue persist, try and send us a request id (header) that failed.

Comment: having the same issues here, whenever I try to call the API using result.getIdToken().getJwtToken(), using header: "Authorization: '+result.getIdToken().getJwtToken() I get an error message: "Authorization header requires 'Credential' parameter. Authorization header requires 'Signature' parameter. Authorization header requires 'SignedHeaders' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a 'X-Amz-Date' or a 'Date' header. Authorization=...."

Comment: @fdreger, If you are re-deploying to the original stage and still having issues, we can investigate. Contact us via AWS forums where you can PM us more info.

Comment: @Balaji: thank you for your help, your answer was precise and definite (unlike the docs). I wasn't able to fix the original problem, but I also wasn't able to reproduce it when trying to set up things from scratch. I would prefer to spend more time investigating this, but the project has moved on (for other reasons) and currently I have no spare time to pursue the truth (which is probably that I made some silly mistake somewhere)